# Can I send a mobile text message with the GUI?

Tags: gui, sms

I've read that you can send text messages via the terminal but is there a way I can send a mobile text message without having to do it in a terminal?

Comment: `apt-cache search sms | grep -iw sms` shows several choices.

Comment: @waltinator I want to know if there is an app like the Microsoft's mysms that I can download from the software center and not have to go into the terminal and do a list of commands.